# Polymer/shadow dom universal selector with selectors

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to understand the specification for Polymer and shadow dom i.e. http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#distribution-algorithms and how content insertion points with a selector work with a universal selector.

The specification is difficult to follow so I'll explain what I'm trying to understand (this is copying/quoting from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)

I have a document:

```
<div id="nameTag">
   <div class="first">Bob</div>
   <div>B. Love</div>
   <div class="email">bob@</div>
</div>
```

And a shadow root with selectors:

```
<div style="background: purple; padding: 1em;">
   <div style="color: red;">
      <content select=".first"></content>
   </div>
   <div style="color: yellow;">
      <content select="div"></content>
   </div>
   <div style="color: blue;">
      <content></content>
   </div>
</div>
```

Notice I've changed the html5rocks example to a universal selector at the end i.e. `<content></content>`

What is the expected behaviour here?

Are content insertion points with a selector allowed along side a universal selector?

Will the universal selector assume any leftover host nodes (not sure if that is the right description).

FYI, I could be incorrectly describing the terminology, it's a difficult specification to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use content blocks with a universal selector alongside custom ones. [This](https://github.com/Polymer/core-toolbar/blob/8b7ce54f24daaebc95a85621c5f9febfa8e2dac1/core-toolbar.html#L70) [is](https://github.com/Polymer/core-tooltip/blob/d1c3916cb413823f5739f960feefdfa5ff8c9327/core-tooltip.html#L67) [actually](https://github.com/Polymer/core-scaffold/blob/c3f8a2ba3c26be5c5d247e45af8a1082f39c5508/core-scaffold.html#L97) [quite](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dialog/blob/85845c655c0eeda2860afd406f606a633911397b/paper-dialog.html#L81) [common](https://github.com/Polymer/core-menu/blob/63caf54d4368e3e81a9744aa3d5f0b56a055ff8d/core-submenu.html#L54). Content blocks get access to the children [in order](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#ex4a), so a universal selector means all nodes not inserted previously will be inserted there. In this case, the `<content select="div">` will select the last two children, so your universal `<content>` will get none.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I realise now my edited example didn't make sense, really the last `div` should have been a `span` (or something else).  In that case the universal selector would have assumed the `span`

Comment: Actually, I just realised that goes against what the html5rocks page describes e.g. `The answer is that Bob’s email address appears once, and it is yellow.` That seems to indicate that the first `select="div"` matches only the first child element and not subsequent host nodes which also match?

Comment: No, that says that the third child element (the email div) only gets matched *to* the second `<content>` once. That's true. A given child node will only appear inside a single `<content>`. Conversely, a single `<content>` node can select many children. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry I'd misread, yes it makes sense & thanks for the replies. I've marked as answered